# Private key decrypting symmetric key, but giving different results when the symmetric key is networked?

Tags: java, networking, encoding, utf-8, rsa

I'm developing a small authentication scheme using RSA and RC4. At my current point, I am trying to send a randomly generated session key to the client, encrypted using the client's public key. From there, the client will read the session key, and decrypt it using its private key, then send a hash back to the server (I won't go into the finer security mechanisms because they are not part of the problem).

Currently, I have confirmed that the server has an identical copy of the client's public key. I know that the server is encrypting the randomly generated session key with the client's public key. So there are [most likely] no problems there.

I think the issue lies within the transfer of the key. The key is of a String type, and is initialized as so -

```
String sessionKey = new BigInteger(128, server.random).toString(128);
```

and is transferred to the client using a DataOutputStream -

```
o.writeUTF(this.encryptedSessionKey);
```

*encryptedSessionKey* is a normal String, no specific encoding. I'm thinking that maybe, when decrypting, the [Java modified UTF-8](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/DataInput.html#readUTF%28%29) encoding, malforms the session key. I decrypt as so -

```
this.sessionKey = new String(cryptUtil.rsaDecrypt(clientPrivateKey, this.encryptedSessionKey.getBytes())); 
// Where encryptedSessionKey is read from the stream using i.readUTF();
```

Would using String.getBytes() on a String encoded in Java modified UTF-8 (read from DataInputStream.readUTF()) return different data from a String instantiated with no specific encoding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that you're doing something like this:

```
byte[] encryptedSessionKeyAsBytes = cipher.doFinal(...);
String encryptedSessionKey = new String(encryptedSessionKeyAsBytes);
```

This is wrong. The String constructor is using the default platform encoding to transform bytes into chars. And all sequence of bytes can't be transformed into chars. For example, if your default encoding is ASCII, all the negative bytes can't be transformed into chars.

If you have to transfer binary data, then transfer it as bytes (using the byte[] type), or use Base64 to transform the bytes into printable chars, and use a writer with ASCII, ISO-8859-1 or UTF-whatever encoding to transfer the Base-64 string.